# how to specify user name in host file of ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am using the host file as below,

```
[qa-workstations]
10.39.19.190 ansible_user=test ansible_ssh_pass=test
```

I am using below command to execute "whoami" command in host

```
root@Svr:~/ansible# ansible all -a "whoami" -i /etc/ansible/host
10.39.19.190 | success | rc=0 >>
root
```

ansible by default trying to use user name in which I have logged in, i.e root instead of test user which I have specified in host file

It works fine when I try to pass the username in ansible cli command

```
root@Svr:~/ansible# ansible all -a "whoami" -i /etc/ansible/host -u test
10.39.19.190 | success | rc=0 >>
test
```

But its not possible for me to pass username every time in CLI as different host uses different username. Also I don't have a key pair generated for each host, because host machine keeps changing often

version used:

```
 ansible 1.5.4 
 Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Create an ansible.cfg in your playbook directory or modify the "global" ansible.cfg

**Note:** Only 1 configuration file is processed. First one wins in the below list.
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html

> - ANSIBLE_CONFIG (an environment variable)
> - ansible.cfg (in the current directory)
> - .ansible.cfg (in the home directory)
> - /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg

```
[defaults]
remote_user=test
```

Comment: This ansible.cfg is good to know, but the issue here is I need to provide different user name/password for different host

Comment: Try inventory variable `ansible_ssh_user`

Comment: Dead link to docs...

Answer (score 43):

With recent versions of Ansible, you can use the `ansible_user` parameter in the host definition.

For example, on the host `mysql-host.mydomain` the user I need to connect with is `mysql` :

```
[docker-hosts]
mysql-host.mydomain ansible_user=mysql
```

But as you are using an older version of ansible, you might need to use `ansible_ssh_user` instead

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/faq.html#how-do-i-handle-different-machines-needing-different-user-accounts-or-ports-to-log-in-with